# Smoothness of solution map for PDE

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, micro-local-analysis

I am wondering what sort of results are available for the following sort of problem, or where to look in the literature for work dealing with such problems, especially in the degenerate elliptic context. It seems like there should be a general functional-analytic framework, but I'm not sure where to look.

Suppose that one has an order-$N$ (nonlinear) differential operator $P:C^\infty\to C^\infty$ which for any $k\geq N$ extends to a map $C^{k,\alpha}\to C^{k-N,\alpha}$ which is smooth as a map between Banach spaces. Suppose that $P$ has an inverse $Q:C^\infty\to C^\infty$. Suppose that there is $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, for any $k\geq 0$, $Q$ has a unique continuous extension to a map $C^{k,\alpha}\to C^{k+m,\alpha}$. Is $Q$ necessarily smooth as a map between these Banach spaces?

Comment: For elliptic operators, smoothness of the solution operator is established in Section II.3.3 of "Nash-Moser Inverse Fuction Theorem" by R. Hamilton (1982).

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Hamilton's paper, but doesn't that only cover the case of linear $P$?

Comment: Yes, he only discusses the linear case but for operators depending on parameters. This allows you then to use the Nash-Moser inverse function theorem to conclude that a non-linear solution operator exists (locally) and is smooth. You might be also interested in my PhD thesis https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.00744 (non-linear elliptic operators are discussed in section 2.2.4)

Comment: Aren't there still two differences? 1) Hamilton's conclusions assert tameness, but nothing about the degree of tameness; 2) the conclusion on smoothness is as a map $C^\infty\to C^\infty$, which doesn't (?) automatically extend to smoothness as a map $C^{k,\alpha}\to C^{k+m,\alpha}$

Comment: How do you establish the existence of $Q$? Did you use a Nash-Moser argument? Or probably something better, because normally the resulting $m$ would be negative and $k$ would have to be sufficiently. large.

Comment: And perhaps you should edit the title, either removing "elliptic" or inserting "degenerate". The situation is much simpler if the PDE is elliptic, because $m = N$.

Comment: @DeaneYang Is it so simple even in the elliptic case? In well-known cases like e.g. the Calabi-Yau complex Monge-Ampère equation, even once one has a solution map $C^{k,\alpha}\to C^{k+2,\alpha}$ and the PDE is known to be uniformly elliptic at the solutions, it doesn't seem totally obvious that the map $C^{k,\alpha}\to C^{k+2,\alpha}$ is smooth. (*Is* it smooth? It seems like it could follow from estimates for the linearized equation, but it isn't obvious to me how. Is it analytic?)

Comment: In the elliptic case, you have a smooth map $F: A \rightarrow B$, where the linearization $F'(a): A \rightarrow B$ is is smooth and has a bounded inverse. In that case, I believe everything follows by the same argument you would use in the finite dimensional inverse function theorem. It basically follows by implicit differentiation.

Comment: So if you can find two Banach spaces, where the linearization of your nonlinear PDE is a smooth map between the two spaces and the inverse of the linearization is bounded, then I'm pretty sure the inverse to the nonlinear map is smooth, too. If the inverse maps back into a weaker space, then you need to use the Nash-Moser theorem. You'll get a smooth inverse, but it will be $C^{k,\alpha} \rightarrow C^{k-m,\alpha$ for some large $m$. The argument here is actually the same as for the Banach implicit function theorem.

Comment: Like I asked Tobias in my second comment above, isn't there some technical difficulty about which function spaces one identifies for the inverse map to be smooth? In Hamilton's paper, it seems that the only conclusion is that the map $C^\infty\to C^\infty$ is smooth and tame, and it seems like the Hamilton-Nash proof does not (and possibly is incapable of?) finding any kind of optimal $m$ for $C^{k,\alpha}\to C^{k+m,\alpha}$ to be smooth. But maybe I don't understand it properly.

Comment: Also I'm curious why you say that $m$ is usually negative? My impression was that the loss of derivatives is typically somewhat small, at least small enough that you gain *some* regularity in passing from the RHS to the solution. Is this wrong?

Comment: The Nash-Moser theorem does give an inverse between two Banach spaces, just not the two you start with. It does not give you the optimal one. That probably requires arguments specific to a PDE. And, in most versions of Nash-Moser, if the inverse to the linearization loses derivatives, the inverse to the nonlinear PDE loses a *lot* of derivatives. A near optimal version is in a paper by Hormander. (http://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol10/vol10pp255-259.pdf).

Comment: I just found a nice short proof by Saint Raymond of the Nash-Moser implicit function theorem. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a21a/e45e8e408fe2bc97cde4741b6e3c25360fa2.pdf